# Maven dependencies red underlines

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

Having problems with maven dependencies, there are red underscores under several dependencies in maven tool window, any ideas about how to solve this?

thanks in advance

[screenshot of intelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XhSH.png)

Comment: right click on the pom.xml and Maven->Reimport. Does it work when you run mvn package on the command line?

Comment: doesn't work for me in this case...

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be one of these.

1. First try to refresh Maven. If you are using Intellij IDEA, Maven overlap is in right side. Just click refresh button and take a while.
2. Delete dependencies in your .m2 directory and repeat the method in 1.

Comment: do I need to delete all dependencies in .m2?

Comment: i deleted the .m2 folder and reinstall all dependencies using `mvn clean install`,
 still got an error...
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project springbootcsv: There are test failures.`

Comment: But now you get test failures! The maven build works

Answer (score 0):

Well this is very common thing to happen.

1. Right Click on `pom.xml` and re-import (Sometime doesn't work because of cache)
2. use command `mvn idea:idea` (This will certainly work for you)

If doesn't work you might have dependencies missing in your repository, check all what you added. More details might be needed then to resolve your issue.

Assumption taken is that you have already ran basic command `mvn clean install`.

Comment: So not use `mvn idea:idea` it's outdated a long time...IDEA handles that better ...`mvn clean verify` but not `mvn clean install`

Comment: I tried both mvn clean verify and mvn clean install, the same error occurred:

[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   StudentInfoApplicationTests.contextLoads ? IllegalState Failed to load Applica...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project springbootcsv: There are test failures.